# How Is this VLOOKUP Not Working?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

```
VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet6!$A$1:$B$202,2,FALSE)
```

On my main sheet I have these two columns

```
COL A               COL B
Dustin Johnson      VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet6!$A$1:$B$202,2,FALSE)
Rickie Fowler       VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet6!$A$1:$B$202,2,FALSE)
Hideki Matsuyama    VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet6!$A$1:$B$202,2,FALSE)
Jon Rahm            VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet6!$A$1:$B$202,2,FALSE)
```

On Sheet6 I have these two columns (202 rows worth)

```
COL A           COL B
Chez Reavie     1
Jordan Spieth   2
Dustin Johnson  T3
Kyle Stanley    T3
Ryan Armour     5
```

This should be searching for Dustin Johnson on Sheet6, finding it in row3 and returning the 2nd column value of T3. But its returning an error, what am I missing here?

Comment: if you do a `=A1=Sheet6!A3` is it `TRUE` ? (just use 2 cells which should be the same but give an error)... Also `=INDEX(Sheet6!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet6!A:A,0))` is a valid formula (just avoid `LOOKUP` by default)

Comment: Check your data for spaces that do not exist int he other.

Comment: It was the space between the first and last name on Sheet6. I dunno what the difference was but I did a search and replace for whatever was between them and replaced it with a real space and this fixed the problem.

Comment: look into the two functions TRIM and CLEAN